# how do I open and read a file using ifstream in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I would like to open a file and read a line from it. There will be only one line in the file so I don't really need to worry about looping, although for future reference it would be nice to know how to read multiple lines.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    // argv[1] holds the file name from the command prompt

    int number = 0; // number must be positive!

    // create input file stream and open file
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(argv[1]);

    if (ifs == NULL) {
        // Unable to open file
        exit(1);
    } else {
        // file opened
        // read file and get number
        ...?
        // done using file, close it
        ifs.close();
    }
}
```

How would I do this? Also, am I handling the file open correctly in terms of successful open?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a C++ book?  If so, have you looked in its chapter discussing the standard I/O library?  If not, I'd strongly recommend getting one of the introductory books listed in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: I don't have a C++ book. I was looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/ and I was confused by the `streamsize n` parameter.

Comment: If you click to the `streamsize` page, it says: "The type is an implementation-defined synonym of one of the signed basic integral types (generally signed int or signed long)."

Comment: `n` is the size of the buffer that `s` points to. If you use the global `getline` instead of the member `getline`, then you don't have to worry about that parameter, because global `getline` reads into a `std::string` object rather than a buffer, and `std::string` objects are resizeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You can read a number with the `>>` stream extraction operator: `ifs >> number`.
2. The standard library function [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) will read a line from a file, if you want a full line of text.
3. To check if the file opened, just write `if (ifs)` or `if (!ifs)`. Leave out the `== NULL`.
4. You don't need to explicitly close the file at the end. That will happen automatically when the `ifs` variable goes out of scope.

Revised code:

```
if (!ifs) {
    // Unable to open file.
} else if (ifs >> number) {
    // Read the number.
} else {
    // Failed to read number.
}
```

Comment: .. how would I handle whitespace?

Comment: By default white space is silently dropped by the operator>>

Answer (score 1):

For what you're doing here, simply:

```
ifs >> number;
```

Will extract a number from the stream and store it in 'number'.

Looping, depends on the content. If it was all numbers, something like:

```
int x = 0;
while (ifs >> numbers[x] && x < MAX_NUMBERS)
{
 ifs >> number[x];
 x++;
}
```

Would work to store a series of numbers in an array. This works because extraction operator's side effect is true if the extraction succeeds, or false if it fails (due to end of file or disk errors, etc.)

Comment: (If anyone saw this in the first 2 minutes, I left out the actual extraction in my first pass)

Comment: Heheh, next time just ninja edit it right in and say nothing. That is the Stack Overflow Way.

Comment: @Feaelin... how would I handle whitespace? If the line is something like `   15         `, I just want to get `15` out of there.

Comment: @Hristo Whitespace is skipped over by `>>`. Try it and see!